# How to add the image to top-left corner of uicollectionView cell in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uibutton

I want to add button to the top-left corner of `UICollectionViewCell`. I am able to add the button on top left of cell but it does not appear on top of the cell, but under the cell. Please tell me how can I do that ?

**I am using below code:**
 [image]

```
_deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
    _deleteButton.center = CGPointMake(9, 10);
    _deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [_deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:_deleteButton];

    [_deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Edit:**
**I want to make delete icon like this:**
[image]

Comment: try to debug by set `_deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` And remove this line `_deleteButton.center = CGPointMake(9, 10);`

Comment: And where do you handle `_deleteButton`?

Comment: what do you mean by.."I am able to to add the button on top left of cell but it does not appear on top of cell but under the cell", please provide some more detail...

Comment: You're using autolayout?

Comment: kumar, please pick the answer to your question so everyone else knows how to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding it to the content view of the cell?
`[cell.contentView addSubview:_deleteButton];`

Answer (score 2):

use bringSubviewToFront in UIView:

```
[cell bringSubviewToFront:_deleteButton];
```

reference: [UIView bringSubviewToFront](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:)

to achieve the effect on the top left corner out of cell's bound, you should follow Islam Q's answer by move the deletebutton's frame outside of cell's bound, and set cell's clip subview to NO.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `cross_30` png file 1x version size matches `delButtonSize`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cell = ...
    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    testButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize);
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:testButton];
    // ...
    return cell;
}
```

It should show a button with redColor at top left on the cell.

This code is only for test purpose. Ideally you do not want to create a new instance of `UIButton` for every cell. Instead, where you are creating the cell in `StoryBoard` or in `nib` file. Add an `UIButton` there. So iOS can reuse the cell with button.

Make sure all the views (except delete button) on the cell has a left and top padding. Space on left and top will make the delete button at `origin` (0, 0) seems like outside of the left top bounds on the cell.

There are some other ways which involve subclassing the UIButton. But those can lead to tricky situations. I prefer rearranging the views in your sutuation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the full code of how I would do what you want to perform :

First of all, create a subclass of UICollectionViewCell. 
Let's call it CustomCell, and give it a public property UIButton called deleteButton. Then, in CustomCell.m :

```
#define delButtonSize 60

// Lazy load the deleteButton
- (UIButton *)deleteButton
{
    if ( !_deleteButton)
    {
        _deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
        _deleteButton.center = CGPointMake(9, 10);
        _deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_deleteButton];

        [_deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    return _deleteButton;
}

// Here we remove all the custom stuff that we added to our subclassed cell
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.deleteButton removeFromSuperview];
    self.deleteButton = nil;
}


- (void) deleteRecipe
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DeleteCell" object:self];
}
```

Now in your ViewController, do this :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //[cell.deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.deleteButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}


- (void) deleteCell:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:(CustomCell *)notification.object];
     [self.contentData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
}
```

I tested my code, it worked perfectly on my computer. 
Hope it helps !

Comment: I am not able to add the button

Answer (score 1):

Set the `center` of your `button` to be {0:0} and ask the `cell` not to cut subviews beyond its borders:

```
_deleteButton.center = cell.bounds.origin;
cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using 1 button for all cells, try create 1 button for 1 cell:

```
    UIButton * deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
    deleteButton.center = CGPointMake(9, 10);
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:deleteButton];
```

Comment: That is not an issue.This approach does not work.I want to improve the location of the button.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of cake :)

I grabbed this [source code](http://www.makemegeek.com/uicollectionview-example-ios/) and put the lay outing code into it like this. My solution will use `AutoLayout`.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // [...] some code from the source code 
    collectionImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    collectionImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.clipsToBounds = NO; // display subviews which will be out of bounds

    CGFloat deleteButtonSize = 20;

    UIButton *yourButtonView = [UIButton new];
    yourButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    yourButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = deleteButtonSize / 2.0;
//  [yourButtonView addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:yourButtonView];

    // setup autolayout constraints
    [yourButtonView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButtonView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:deleteButtonSize].active = YES;
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButtonView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:deleteButtonSize].active = YES;

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButtonView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:deleteButtonSize * 0.2].active = YES;
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButtonView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:deleteButtonSize * 0.2].active = YES;
    // deleteButtonSize * 0.2 is the offset here

    return cell;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to design your custom `UICollectionViewCell` which has been designed accordingly and reuse the same with given identifier.